# Offer some REST API resources for specified clients

Tags: api, angularjs, rest

I think there is no solution for problem we're facing, but for confirmation I would like to you ask here.

We have REST API that is consumed from:

- administration website (AngularJS)
- customer website (AngularJS)
- other REST API clients (own API applications)

Because requests from administration/customer website are made by AngularJS at a client side, users are able to determine (e.g. via FireBug) resources URLs and are able to consume all these resources from their own applications - what we don't want to and we cannot to restrict it e.g. with IP address because requests go from client. We would like to offer some group of resources only for customer / administration website and some resources for own REST API clients and some resources for both, but from the principle of JS requests made from AngularJS (and resource URL visibility) it cannot be done(?).

What could be the best practice for this issue?

Comment: Can you restrict cross domain requests to only the urls for your own applications?

Comment: No. We need a solution that works cross platform and cross technology :/

Comment: What's wrong with just applying authorization at the API layer to allow/deny requests based on the users making the calls?

Comment: Because I don't know if the HTTP request is made from our Website (AngularJS) or from API client like mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Your REST resources should always be secure. You should never depend on any client side javascript code. If your security is breached because someone *knows* the URI of an REST api; something is **very wrong**.

Angular can be made modular is such a way that the customers only see the customer modules and the administrators see the customer and administrator modules. This way you can let the administrators play in a WYSIWYG environment without having them to switch back and forth between the websites.

```
// Customers.js
// Module only containing customer code
angular.module('myCustomerProducts', ['myMainApp']);

// Administrators.js
// Module only containing administrator code
angular.module('myEditCustomerProducts', ['myCustomerProducts', 'myMainApp']);
```

Since your website is already separated for administrators and customers you can simply only include and deploy the javascript code for the specified target site. If this is not the case you'll need some server side transformation (eg. ASP.NET, PHP, Jade, ...) to build the index.html dynamically based on the credentials of the user. 
Depending on the hosting platform, you can also deny access to everyone not in the administrator group when requesting anything from the administrator website (area).

But again; the server side security is way more of value. You can't secure an insecure server with javascript (on the client side).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain it correctly in my original question. My problem is not how to secure my REST API, we're facing the issue that I am not able to recognize if the request is from client website or some another client application. De facto I need to solve ACL problem and allow some API resources for particular type of the user.

Comment: Why should that be a security issue? A user should not have extra server side permissions just because he's using a custom REST client instead of the website. What kind of issues are you having?

Comment: No, it is not a security issue (user is authorized because he has a access token because he provided a valid credentials). But some REST API resources are not designed for another REST client instead of the website and I don't want to user call them outside the website. It's not a security problem de facto.

Comment: Ah! :) What probably should work is letting the server generate a cookie on the initial browser request and let the client include this with every request. On those specific api resources you check for the existence of the cookie. If it's not there; it's not a browser.